# I need to call URL from shell script that contains some special characters.How would I perform this?

Tags: shell, unix

I need to call URL from shell script that contains some special characters but the problem is that these characters has some special meaning in shell hence the shell sending the process in background.How would I perform this?

Please suggest, thanks in advance...

```
curl localhost:8009/customer/v1/data_extract?epoch_from=15448&epoch_to=15402&limit=500&bucket=Activity&address_bus=mainDatabase&where_field=cj.journal_identity_tx.created_dt_tm.epoch_created_dt_tm
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace every `&` with `%26`

Replace every `=` with `%3d`

Or use `"`url`"` or use single quotes `'`.

Double and single quotes have different meanings in `bash`

Comment: By doing this I am getting curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8009; Connection refused  ERROR

Comment: Which are you doing % replacement or quotes not both together.

Comment: I am hitting like this: 'localhost:8009/customer/v1/customers/data_extract?epoch_from%3d154038%26epoch_to%3d1540388%26limit%3d500%26bucket%3dActivityJournalStore%26address_bus%3dmainDatabase%26where_field%3dcj.journal_identity_tx.created_dt_tm.epoch_created_dt_tm'

Comment: `curl "localhost:8009/customer/v1/data_extract?epoch=01012017&epoch_to=31122018&address_bus=mainDatabase"` use double quotes like this